# can we get totalcount and last record from postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am having table having 23 records , I am trying to get total count of record and last record also in single query. something like that

```
select count(*) ,(m order by createdDate)  from music m ;
```

is there any way to pull this out only last record as well as total count in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using window functions

```
select *
from (
   select m.*, 
          row_number() over (order by createddate desc) as rn,
          count(*) over () as total_count
   from music
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Another option would be to use a scalar sub-query and combine it with a `limit` clause:

```
select *, 
       (select count(*) from order_test.orders) as total_count
from music
order by createddate desc
limit 1;
```

Depending on the indexes, your memory configuration and the table definition might be faster then the two window functions.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not not possible to do what is being asked, sql does not function that way, the second you ask for a count (*) sql changes the level of your data to an aggregation. The only way to do what you are asking is to do a count(*) and order by in a separate query.

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this can be done in a nested query using window functionality but according to the question I think the user wants a single line type of query , also computationally, for a large dataset, the nested query would perform slower than two individual queries

Comment: How do you know the single query would perform slower? Did you test it? Both window functions can be evaluated by the database in a single query - typically a Seq Scan in Postgres. With two queries you wind up with two Seq Scans which is twice the work.

Comment: Yep, evaluated it. Your query vs two queries - query 1 count(*) , query 2 select top 1* after an order by

Comment: This is a table with 23 rows, and OP never said performance or query length was of any concern ... I don't think it is a good idea to answer things that are not true deliberately just because you think OP wanted to ask something different that what he actually asked ^^

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using windowing functions and no subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(*) OVER w, last_value(m) OVER w
FROM music m
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY date DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

The point here is that last_value applies on partitions defined by windows and not on groups defined by GROUP BY.

I did not perform any test but I suspect my solution to be the less effective amongst the three already posted. But it is also the closest to your example query so far.